# How to get list of questions that used to have a bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

Of course the questions with a current bounty are in the featured list. But how to get the questions that used to have a bounty? I'd like to have a look through them since other than votes a bounty is a decent indicator if the question was any good/valuable to someone.

(by "used to have a bounty" I mean where the bounty has been awarded some time ago)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Stack Exchange Data Explorer query

- [Questions with bounties awarded in the past](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/471411/questions-with-bounties-awarded-in-the-past),

written by yours truly, gets you that list. If you want more specific search criteria (like tags or bounty amounts) it is easy to fork the query and make it do what you want.